# How to mount a drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I want to mount a disk with `mount /dev/nvme1n1 /disk1` but im getting this error: `mount: /disk1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

Supporting info:

1.

```
root@ip:~# fdisk -l | grep '^Disk'
Disk /dev/loop0: 24.10 MiB, 26189824 bytes, 51152 sectors
Disk /dev/loop1: 26.65 MiB, 27930624 bytes, 54552 sectors
Disk /dev/loop2: 55.5 MiB, 58183680 bytes, 113640 sectors
Disk /dev/loop3: 42.18 MiB, 44220416 bytes, 86368 sectors
Disk /dev/loop4: 61.85 MiB, 64835584 bytes, 126632 sectors
Disk /dev/loop5: 61.92 MiB, 64901120 bytes, 126760 sectors
Disk /dev/loop6: 67.25 MiB, 70508544 bytes, 137712 sectors
Disk /dev/loop7: 67.83 MiB, 71106560 bytes, 138880 sectors
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 558.81 GiB, 600000000000 bytes, 1171875000 sectors
Disk model: Amazon EC2 NVMe Instance Storage        
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Disk model: Amazon Elastic Block Store              
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x24ca9e81
Disk /dev/nvme2n1: 558.81 GiB, 600000000000 bytes, 1171875000 sectors
Disk model: Amazon EC2 NVMe Instance Storage
```

2. 

```
root@ip-172-31-2-140:~# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0    25M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
loop1         7:1    0  26.7M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5163
loop2         7:2    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2253
loop3         7:3    0  42.2M  1 loop /snap/snapd/14066
loop4         7:4    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1242
loop5         7:5    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1405
loop6         7:6    0  67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835
loop7         7:7    0  67.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22753
nvme1n1     259:0    0 558.8G  0 disk 
nvme0n1     259:1    0     8G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:3    0     8G  0 part /
nvme2n1     259:2    0 558.8G  0 disk
```

Comment: Hello. what is the file system type of the drive that is causing this error? If I am reading the information you have included in the question correctly I see the disk type is DOS?

Comment: Have you tried the `-o nouuid` option while also specifying the filesystem type, e.g., ext4, ntfs, etc. using `-t filetype` where `filetype` is the actual filetype (btw, it is most likely not dos)?

Comment: @mook765 Unless the disk has no partitions.

Comment: Please partition your disk first: one does not mounts disks, one mounts partitions.